# Provide Generic type as one of many in Material Table Datasource Implementation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular Material's Mat Table and need to make a custom DataSource for the same .
Since I'll be using Material Table multiple times throughout my project I am thinking of making a Reusable DataSource implementation.

```
export class CommonDataSource implements DataSource<SourceData> {
  private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<SourceData[]>([]);

  constructor(public httpService : ParamExtractor) {}
  
  loadData(paramsObj: DataSourceParamsObject) {
    this.loadingSubject.next(true);
    this.showTableSubject.next(true);
    
    this.httpService
      .extractParamsAndCallDataLoader(paramsObj)
        .subscribe((response : PaginatedResponse<SourceData>) => {
        this.dataSubject.next(response['data']);
      });
  }
}
```

The Problem I am having is in the SourceData type provided in the first line ,

```
export class CommonDataSource implements DataSource<SourceData>
```

Since I am reusing this everywhere with multiple data types ,
I have defined SourceData as :

```
import { TopupReport } from './topupReport';
import { Transaction } from './transaction';

export type SourceData = Transaction | TopupReport;
```

After reading about Union types in Typescript , `SourceData`will have the properties **common** properties of Transaction and TopupReport  .
I want it to be Either Transaction OR TopupReport.

The list of possible types of SourceData will be bigger as the app grows and I reuse the CommonSourceData in more places.

How Can I provide something like this :

```
type SourceData = TypeA || TypeB || TypeC
```

Where SourceData can take either of those values.

EDIT 1 :
I want to do something like

```
class CommonDataSource implements DataSource<T>{
 private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<T[]>([]);
...
```

But Typescript wont allow me to do so.

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/50589861/5514820

Comment: @er-sho what the answer is doing is kind of different to what I need .
If I can just know how to Either OR the types i'll get my answer .

The question is not much about angular material table as much as its about type conditions in Typescript.

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same problem. If you happend to find a solution, I would love the hear it! @PiyushD

Answer (score 0):

To pass a generic to `DataSource`, your class must accept a generic.

```
class CommonDataSource<Data> implements DataSource<Data>{
 private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Data[]>([]);
...
```

(I've named the generic `Data` instead of `T`)

---

In response to your comment:

> After reading about Union types in Typescript , SourceDatawill have the properties common properties of Transaction and TopupReport . I want it to be Either Transaction OR TopupReport.

A union type *is* what you want. `Transaction | TopupReport` can be thought of as `Transaction` OR `TopupReport`. Because you don't know which type it is, only the common properties will be available to you. If you want to access a property that is unique to one of the types, you need to first make sure the data is indeed of that type:

```
interface Transaction {
  name: string;
  amount: number;
}

interface TopupReport {
  name: string;
  total: number;
}

function getAmountOrTotal(data: Transaction | TopupReport) {
  // we can always use `name` since it exists on both models.
  console.log(data.name)
  // @ts-expect-error we can't use `amount` because we might be dealing with a `TopupReport`
  console.log(data.amount)
  if ('amount' in data) {
    // now we know `amount` exists
    return data.amount;
  } else {
    return data.total;
  }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpTiAzoswD2IyA3gFDLIhwC2EAXMlmFKAOYDc5yN+AruAxC9qAI2icAvqVKhIsRClT4ADr2UAlCMvxQwJLlVoMmLEBy5h8YOABtBwsVEnSY-BHkLJWEMAEFqfOAA8lBK1jYAFAAmcNYM6Jg47gREAD5oKmqa2roAlPoUAPSFyADuKAiY3DalcACeWMi8WCgABoYQrYygSMjAehAAHsBMjZ4iVgAWyAFREDZYAHRcCIRY+DYQizb4rNGxcIsduVzFyAACYFgAtEPKEO63UFA6ZRWYAOR6zW08-GBdMSVH5vGbAViTPRiZBzWxsMr9aZwZCtJSqDRaHQAlZrDZbHZ7GLWRZ-cAnCjAGDICIfUlgD59IhEuD5MgUIolED4UqggDWXJ5rTpXSGIyuXAoUB8vCgTIOJIC-04FAkyHmLQK7KlYBlcuJlnCyuQUgkQA)